# Find highest age of person in Array and return name

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, return

Task: your task is to expand the class `PersonRegister` through coding the method `nameOftheOldest()`. The methods task is to find and return the name of the person that is the oldest in the register (that is the oldest of those stored in the list `allPersons` array).

Code of the class looks like this:

```
public class PersonRegister
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private Person[] allPersons;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class PersonRegister
     */
    public PersonRegister(int numberOfPersons)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.allPersons = new Person[numberOfPersons];
    }
    
    public void registreraPerson(int index, Person aPerson)
    {
        
        allPersons[index] = aPerson;
        
    }
}
```

There is another class called Person in the program that looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String name;
    private int birthYear;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class ExperimentJavaLoops
     */
    public Person(String name, int birthYear)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.name = name;
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }
    
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
        
    }
    
    public int birthYear()
    {
        return birthYear;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        
    }
    
    public void setbirthYear(int birthYear)
    {
        
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
        
    }
}
```

Googled this a lot, read literature and tried to code it but cant find a solution. I think I'm supposed to loop through the array and compare values inside the loop through an if-statement. Then also use external method calls to get the name and birthyear (oldest will be the person with lowest birthyear, naturally). And it should be converted to String and returned in order to return name? Confused. Very new to programming and a bit more used to ArrayLists than Arrays.

Comment: You need to create a comparator that compares `Person` objects by birthYear. That's the best solution. Other solution is brute force. Sort by getting the age year and swap (like a bubblesort).

Comment: @hfontanez Sorting is overkill. It's simpler and more efficient to iterate through the array and keep track of the oldest person so far.

Comment: The approach outlined at the beginning of the last paragraph is sound. So please show us what you have tried. Not sure what you mean by "use external method calls". What would you need them for? You have all the information you need right there in your `Person` class.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I never said that sorting was an optimal solution. In fact, you seem to ignore that my initial recommendation was to create a comparator AND that I mentioned it was the best solution.

Comment: @hfontanez My comment didn't imply that you said it was the best solution; but why mention it at all? In fact, creating a comparator is *also* overkill for OP (but I agree that in real-world code it would *usually* be the best solution). Given their level, it's best to have a dumb, manual `for` loop that compares the ages in each iteration.

Comment: I suggest to change (if you can) the `birthYear` variable name to `birthDate` and change its datatype to be `LocalDate`. You can still use g00se solution to figure out the eldest `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a stream approach:

```
    Optional<Person> eldest = Arrays.stream(allPersons)
        .collect(Collectors.maxBy((p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p1.getAge(), p2.getAge())));
    System.out.println("Eldest is " + eldest.get());
```

But you might want to do a simple iteration, keeping track of the current oldest, as has been suggested

Comment: That's how I'd do it, or maybe `Optional<Person> eldest = Arrays.stream(allPersons).max(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge));`. but I don't think OP is ready for streams yet.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

```java
public String nameOfTheOldest()
{
    Person oldest = allPersons[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < allPersons.length; i++)
    {
        if (allPersons[i] ...)
            ...
    }
    return ...;
}
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph

Hm, external method calls: i was thinking because this nameOfTheOldest-method is supposed to be 
in the PersonRegister class and the getName- and birthYear-methods are in the Person class?

Comment: what do you compare allPersons[i] to inside 
the if statement? I get "bad operand types for binary operator"
when i compare it to the oldest-variable.

Comment: Were you doing `if (allPersons[i] > oldest)`? That's not going to work. You need to do `allPersons[i].something()` (but I won't spoil that something exactly).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this. Returns the
age as a string but not the name. Also i get "Exception occurred" if the amount
of Person objects in the array do not match the length of the array when i use the method.

Code:

```
      public String nameOfTheOldest() {
        // oldest == earliest birthYear.
            
            String str= "";
            Person oldest = allPersons[0];
            int oldestINT = oldest.birthYear();
    for (int i = 1; i < allPersons.length; i++)
    {     
        
        Person maybeOldest = allPersons[i];
        int perhapsOldest = maybeOldest.birthYear();
        if (perhapsOldest < oldestINT)
            oldestINT = perhapsOldest;
            
            str = String.valueOf(oldestINT);
            
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If it worked, that wouldn't do what the method says. It would return an age as a `String`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code -

```
    public String nameOfTheOldest() {
    Person oldest = allPersons[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < allPersons.length; i++)
    {
        Person p = allPersons[i];
        if (p.birthYear() < oldest.birthYear()) {
            oldest = p;
        }
    }
    return oldest.name();
}
```